# How to divide stackpanel in 7 equal height rectangles

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, layout, stackpanel

I am working on Windows Phone 8 app wherein I have a Stackpanel and I want to put 7 rectangles in it. I want those rectangles to be of equal height irrespective of screen size. I tried setting `Height="*"` but it is giving error.

```
        <StackPanel>
            <Rectangle Fill="Violet" Height="*"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Indigo" Height="*"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Height="*"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Green" Height="*"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Height="*"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Height="*"></Rectangle>
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Height="*"></Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
```

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: Don't use `StackPanel`. That's not what `StackPanel` is for. Use `Grid`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should do it for you:

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Violet" Grid.Row="0" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Indigo" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="2" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Green" Grid.Row="3" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="4" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Orange" Grid.Row="5" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Row="6" />
</Grid>
```

There is also a `UniformGrid` that can do this for you:

```
<UniformGrid Columns="1" Rows="7" />
```